# if statement suggestion

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, if-statement

I have a javascript i want to compress a little

The basic idea is
it looks for files from a json file
If the file is 
MP4,mkv,avi, < any video format.
It appends the url in a  tag

if its an image it does the same
With an  tag.

here is my code.

```js
//example
var link = "video.mp4";

var videoorimg = link.split(".").pop(1);
        if(videoorimg === "mp4"){
          $("body").append('<video src="'+ link +'">');
        }
        if(videoorimg === "jpg"){
          $("body").append('<img src="'+ link +'">');
        }
```

this is fine. How ever im running into issues where there is multiple file types for images and video.

My idea was an array like this.

```js
//example
function imgarry(){
jpg,
png,
jpeg,
bmp,
tiff,
}

function videoarry(){
mkv,
mp4,
mov,
avi,
m4v,
}


var link = "video.mp4";

var videoorimg = link.split(".").pop(1);
        if(videoorimg === videoarry() ){
          $("body").append('<video src="'+ link +'">');
        }
        if(videoorimg === imgarry() ){
          $("body").append('<img src="'+ link +'">');
        }
```

how ever i know this is incorrect,
Is there a way i can achieve this though?

Comment: `if (videoarry.includes(videorimg))`

Comment: thanks, how im still unsure if my function setup would be correct.
I highly doubt so.

Comment: Change it to this: `let videoarry = [
   "mkv",
   "mp4",
   "mov",
   "avi",
   "m4v"
]
`

Comment: You should be seeing errors in the console in regards to your functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted image and video types should be in arrays instead of functions

```js
   //example
   let imgarry = [
    'jpg',
    'png',
    'jpeg',
    'bmp',
    'tiff',
   ];

   let videoarry = [
    'mkv',
    'mp4',
    'mov',
    'avi',
    'm4v'
   ]


let link = "video.mp4";

let videoorimg = link.split(".").pop(1);

if(videoarry.includes(videoorimg) ) {
   $("body").append('<video src="'+ link +'">');
}

if(imgarry.includes(videoorimg) )v{
   $("body").append('<img src="'+ link +'">');
}
```

Comment: pop() does not have any arguments.

Comment: works great,thank you!
How ever i did change lets to var

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in Vanilla Js:

```
var file = "Image.jpg";


    function ImageOrVideo(file){

        let imgExtensions = ["jpg","png","jpeg","bmp","tiff"],
        vidExtensions = ["mkv","mp4","mov","avi","m4v"],

        ext =  file.split(".").pop(1);

        if(imgExtensions.indexOf(ext) >= 0){
            return "Image!";
        }

        if(vidExtensions.indexOf(ext) >= 0){
            return "video!";
        }

    }

    console.log(ImageOrVideo(file));
```